# Applying Wilson's rating to multiple items

Tags: algorithm

I need to apply [Wilson's rating algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval) to multiple items to give an overall user "score"
Would the best way be to add up all the likes + totals, and pass these straight into my ratingAverage function?
or should I be adding them up, dividing by the number of items, then feeding that into the ratingAverage function?

My ratingAverage function just implements Wilson's rating algorithm by taking 2 parameters; Likes, Total (Likes + Dislikes)

Comment: I've edited your question and added a link to what I **think** you're referring to; please update if wrong!

Comment: That is correct, I didn't think to include it. Thank you!